Set SerializerSettings in NSwag.AspNetCore Version=14.1
I need to set CamelCase configuration for the JsonSerializer used in NSwag, in older version i create an instance of JsonSerializerSettings, set the property ContractResolver and override the SerializerSettings in method AddOpenApiDocument, now i can't find SerializerSettings
This is the code used before:
private void AddSwaggerEndpoints(IServiceCollection services, UnoSwaggerEndpoint[] endpoints)
{
    var nswagDefaultSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
    };

    foreach (var endpoint in endpoints.OrderBy(e => e.DocumentName))
    {
        services.AddOpenApiDocument(o =>
        {
            o.DocumentName = endpoint.DocumentName;
            o.Title = endpoint.Title;
            o.ApiGroupNames = endpoint.ApiGroupName;
            o.SerializerSettings = nswagDefaultSerializerSettings;
            o.SchemaSettings.SchemaNameGenerator = new NestedClassNameSchemaNameGenerator();
            o.Version = endpoint.Version;
            o.SchemaSettings.AllowReferencesWithProperties = true;
            o.SchemaSettings.GenerateEnumMappingDescription = true;
            o.DocumentProcessors.Add(new SignalRTypescriptDocumentProcessor(endpoint));
            o.DocumentProcessors.Add(new SchemaSorterDocumentProcessor());
        });
    }
}


AspNetCoreOpenApiDocumentGeneratorSettings does not have a SerializerSettings property. Please look here, how its implemented now.
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/blob/6f5e5f9006a34b22d8755428026ff6395d8d8631/src/NSwag.Generation.AspNetCore/AspNetCoreOpenApiDocumentGeneratorSettings.cs
To handle JSON serialization with camel case in NSwag,
you typically configure the serializer in ASP.NET Core's default MvcJsonOptions or JsonOptions rather than directly in NSwag.
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    });

or
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    });

EDIT 1: After further investigation I found this:
builder.Services
    .AddOpenApiDocument(options =>
    {
        options.DocumentName = "v2";
        options.Version = "v2";
        options.SchemaSettings = new NewtonsoftJsonSchemaGeneratorSettings
        {
            SchemaType = NJsonSchema.SchemaType.OpenApi3,
            SchemaNameGenerator = new NestedClassNameSchemaNameGenerator(),
            SerializerSettings  = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            }
        };

    });


